# Remove boiler plate using(var db = new MyAppContext) from functions in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, using

It is a standard practice to wrap your data functions in using statement while using entity framework. e.g.

```
using(var db = new MyAppContext())
{
    return db.Books.ToList();
}
```

Often inside there is only one return statement. Is there a way to do this without having to write the using statement every time. With new c# feature the function will be much simpler to write.

```
public IList<Book> GetAllBooks() => db.Books.ToList()
```

There are lots and lots of methods I have that use this using block like that and if there is a way to do without it, it will make code much simpler.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could I ask if what the new feature C# introduced involving this `public IList<Book> GetAllBooks() => db.Books.ToList()`? It does not appear as valid syntax to me. I'm fairly late to update the latest C# version.

Comment: It is new C# 6 syntax. If you can embed a lambda, you could write a helper function and do something like: `Books() => WrapInUsing((Db) => Db.books));` where the `WrapInUsing` function calls its `Action<Db>` param inside the `using`

Comment: It's an [expression-bodied member](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say that I fully approve of what you're wanting, but, the following code:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TOut DisposeWrapper<TDisposable, TOut>(this TDisposable input, Func<TDisposable,TOut> function) where TDisposable:IDisposable
    {
        try
        {
            return function(input);
        }
        finally
        {
            input.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can wrap in using, which has the exact same effect and is perhaps a bit more terse:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TOut DisposeWrapper<TDisposable, TOut>(this TDisposable input, Func<TDisposable,TOut> function) where TDisposable:IDisposable
    {
        using (input) return function(input);
    }
}
```

Will let you do something similar to what you're wanting. It's slightly verbose to use, example:

```
public static int ExampleUsage() => new Example().DisposeWrapper(x => x.SomeMethod());
```

And for completeness, here's the example class I used to test this functionality:

```
public class Example : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I was disposed of");
    }

    public int SomeMethod() => 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you wouldn't approve for this?

Comment: @MuhammadIbraheem simply stated, it's being terse to be terse. That's all.